# install haskell cabal w/o manual dependency resolution

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

I see there's a nice package system called Cabal that handles dependency resolution. So I'm trying to install that so I can get it to install the Haskell OpenGL modules for me. However, Cabal itself has lots of dependencies. Is there a way to install Cabal without manually resolving all of its dependencies? I tried running the bootstrap, but that doesn't seem to do it, because it reports missing modules parsec and network (which in turn have their own dependencies).

Manually building the dep's got me about 3 deep before the mtl module install crapped out on me:

```
user@machine:~/haskell/mtl-1.1.0.2$ runghc Setup build
Preprocessing library mtl-1.1.0.2...
Building mtl-1.1.0.2...

Control/Monad/Cont.hs:74:7:
    Could not find module `Control.Monad':
      Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package base?
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should install the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) ("batteries included")

Comment: Although this helped, I later installed the Haskell Platform and got the same error trying to compile it. I was able to get past it by doing this on ubuntu: apt-get install libghc6-mtl-dev 
Found on: http://rubynugs.blogspot.com/2007/12/next-haskell-error-controlmonadreader.html

Comment: On Mac OSX, I installed the Haskell Platform and ... there weren't enough batteries included. As with nont, even with the Haskell Platform, the mtl library crapped out. Obviously, on OSX, apt-get is not going to solve my problem! It would be nice to have a more general solution.